# How to use hibernate validator on mapped entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to hibernate & spring, i want to know how to use hibernate validator for mapped entity classes, **For example:** If i'm having the following entity classes which has one to one relationship between them. How can i validate the following fields of the two entities using annotations like @NotNull of hibernate validator: " personName, personPhone, personEmail, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, & zipCode ".

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "person" )
public class FacilityModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column ( name = "pers_id" )
    private int persId;

    @Column ( name = "pers_name" )  
    private String personName;

    @OneToOne ( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn ( name = "pers_Addr_Id" )
    private AddressModel address;

    @Column ( name = "pers_phone_no" )
    private String personPhone;

    @Column ( name = "pers_email" )
    private String personEmail;
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "address" )
public class AddressModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column ( name = "addr_id" )
    private int addrId;

    @Column ( name = "addr_address_line1" )
    private String addrLine1;

    @Column ( name = "addr_address_line2" )
    private String addrLine2;

    @Column ( name = "addr_city" )
    private String city;

    @Column ( name = "addr_state" )
    private String state;

    @Column ( name = "addr_country" )
    private String country;

    @Column ( name = "addr_zip_code" )
    private String zipCode;
```

Also, do i need to include any additional codes in the controller other than @Valid annotation and BindingResult in the handler methods.

Please any one help me with this.

Comment: If anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the annotations you want to validate on the fields, and hibernate before to save will check if yours values are right.

http://hibernate.org/validator/

If in your controller, you add the annotation @Valid you can see also that the object you have is not OK to be saved.

Comment: I'm not able to validate the AddressModel class fields.

Comment: @karthi If you add `@Valid` on your `address` property of `FacilityModel` it should cause the validations on your `AddressModel` to start firing.